# python tkinter fast drawing an envelope

Tags: python, numpy, tkinter, graph, line

I want to draw two lines made from two sets of ordinates such as you would find in a graph.

An example would be a sine wave or a triangle wave. I have the ordinates for these lines in a numpy array. However, rather than draw two lines, I want to instead shade the space between these. So, what you end up with is a coloured object with two parallel vertical sides and the top and bottom defined by ordinates stored in the arrays.

I believe this would be doable by drawing lots of parallel lines or suitable shapes but I need to draw these very quickly, so I am looking for an elegant and efficient way of doing it. I need to draw many tens of these shaded area figures each second.

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Just a suggestion but you might want to look at the library `matplotlib`. It allows you to draw graphs and can be put in tkinter windows.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have a canvas onto which this has to go - it has to be background for some other graphics. Can matplotlib draw onto an existing canvas? Does it have this kind of drawing function? And finally; is it fast?

Comment: `matplotlib` isn't my area of expertise so I can't help a lot but I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56228013/11106801